# Barycenter of a binary star system

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion, celestial-mechanics, binary-stars

It is said that the barycenter of 11 Draconis (Thuban) and 10 Draconis which compose a binary star system is a central point.  Is this central point a material or immaterial object? Does the size of the central point depend on the masses of the stars? More generally, what is this point?

Answer (score 1):

The barycenter is just the center of mass. In this case, it is an immaterial point in space, between the two stars, around which they orbit. Its position depends on the masses of the stars.

If the stars are equal in mass, it is halfway between them. If one is twice the mass of the other, it is one-third of the way along the line from the heavy one to the light one.

The general formula for the center of mass for two point masses, $m_1$ at $\mathbf{r}_1$ and $m_2$ at $\mathbf{r}_2$, is

$$\mathbf{r}_{CM}=\frac{m_1\mathbf{r}_1+m_2\mathbf{r}_2}{m_1+m_2}.$$

Comment: For another example, the barycentre of the earth-moon system is inside the earth, 4671 km from the earth's centre.